# Jquery Image slider bug

Tags: jquery, slider

This is my site....
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14080718/nategines.com-peopleperhour/index.html

If you click on the work section you will notice that there is an odd grey bar with some text on the left side of the screen. Now change the size of your browser window. The image resizes itself to fill the width of the browser window. It is supposed to be full sized like this all of the time. This is some kind of resizing error that is happening on my image slider plugin.

I have contacted the developer and he told me to ....
Initialize slider only after it and it's parent are added to DOM, or call updateSliderSize() method.
$('.royalSlider').royalSlider('updateSliderSize');

I have also built this site using Jquery Ui tabs and I am not sure what to do with this code. I am not very experienced with Jquery development and need some help. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To call a function after the DOM has loaded, be sure to use the following:

```
$(function() {
    // Code goes in here.
}
```

If the call is happening after DOM load, then add `$(window).resize();` to the end of the callback.  This will cause the Browsers to render the elements again, this time correctly.

Comment: Ive tried that, but it didnt work. I have built this page using jquery UI tabs. Not sure if code needs to go somewhere in the UI code. Any ideas?

Comment: With a very dynamic site like yours, its hard to follow the code from the browser. I would suggest temporarily simplifying the look/feel so you can figure out the issue. I can see scrolling, tabs, sliders, hashtags,etc which also makes it difficult to debug. Copy the file and remove components that do not relate to this issue. By removing extra fluff it will allow you to focus on the issue.  Once you find where to place the developer's solution you can add that in the original, so you won't lose any progress.